# How can I launch the executeSomething(sfWebRequest $request) in symfony?

Tags: plugins, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am new to Symfony 1.4

I have a plugin and inside the *modules* folder I have `payment` module, and for this, I have the *lib* folder and the *templates* folder. In *lib* I have the `BasePaymentComponents.class.php` class and in this class I have some functions called with the prefix `executeSometing` in this way:

```
public function executeSometing(sfWebRequest $request)
```

An for each execute I have a specific template in *templates* folder. The file structure is like that: `_something1.php`, `_something2.php` ...

My question is in what moment the `executeSometing` function from `BasePaymentComponents.class.php`  is actually executed?

I created another template, named `_something3.php` and set for him the function:

```
public function executeSometing3(sfWebRequest $request)
```

actually is not launching the function. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using components - you add components to a template - so to execute the Something method in the BasePayment component you would add the following to your template :

```
<?php include_component('BasePayment', 'something') ?>
```

Check the docs here -> [Inside the view layer](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer) <- for more info